# prometheus alertmanager - alerting rule for specific pod in eks cluster

Tags: prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a question on Prometheus Alertmanager rule.Trying to create a rule (Measure CPU usage, Disk Usage etc) for specific pods in eks cluster. :

```
- alert: NodeFilesystemSpaceFillingUp
  expr: |
    (
      node_filesystem_avail_bytes{component="node-exporter",fstype!=""} / node_filesystem_size_bytes{component="node-exporter",fstype!=""} < 0.4
    and
      predict_linear(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{component="node-exporter",fstype!=""}[6h], 24*60*60) < 0
    and
      node_filesystem_readonly{component="node-exporter",fstype!=""} == 0
    )
  for: 1h
  labels:
    severity: warning
```

Unable to find a generic way where cluster name and pod name pattern can be passed and rule can be created.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you discribe how you want to pass the pod/cluster name, what do you want to achieve with it?